# VBA - Update timestamp when a row range is edited

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, range, row

I'm having some issues trying to put together a VBA code that will update a timestamp every time something in the row is edited.

So what I need is a time stamp in A3 for when something from B3:CA3 is edited, and so on for every row up to 1000.

I've done some looking around but all of the codes I've found so far only related to a specific column and not a row range...

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: To clarify - by timestamp - I need date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this worksheet event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, Intersection As Range, cell As Range
    Set r = Range("B3:CA1003")
    Set Intersection = Intersect(r, Target)

    If Intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In Intersection
            Range("A" & cell.Row).Value = Date & " " & Time
        Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

To get both the NT username and the application username, try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, Intersection As Range, cell As Range
    Dim s As String

    Set r = Range("B3:CA1003")
    Set Intersection = Intersect(r, Target)
    s = vbCrLf & Environ("USERNAME") & vbCrLf & Application.UserName

    If Intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In Intersection
            Range("A" & cell.Row).Value = Date & " " & Time & s
        Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! Much more simpler then I thought it would be!

Comment: Is it possible to add the 'users name' of who edited the row in column B as well?
I would then change the range of your code from B3 to start from C3.