# Excel Timestamp only when the concatenated range is updated

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out a way to use a dynamic timestamp that updates the time only when the contents of a concatenated range change.

I tried using a defined function that updates the timestamp when the reference text is changed. So far I have a function that updates in column G as desired when I edit text in columns B:E. However, column G also updates if I filter or delete a cell which is not desired.

Is there a way to use a function that only updates when a concatenated range changes and is not affected by filtering or other operations?

Here is closest solution I could find that works with filtering, but I'd like use a function that targets a range vs coding the ranges and targets:
[VBA - Update timestamp when a row range is edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299212/vba-update-timestamp-when-a-row-range-is-edited)

Here is the example workbook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C2WtbiF4vmcsB-xbBlKw4SYVnTca5NiN/view?usp=share_link

Here is the code I use for the function:

```
Function MyTimestamp(Reference As Range)

If Reference.Text <> "" Then

MyTimestamp = Format(Now, "#.#############")

Else

MyTimestamp = ""

End If

End Function
```

I expected the timestamp to only change when the reference text changes, but it also changes when filtering a row or deleting a cell.

Comment: Normal practice is to use the `Worksheet_Change` event for this (or `Worksheet_Calculate` if the reference cell contains a formula).

Comment: Any reason that you want to want to store the timestamp as string and not as date?

Comment: @FunThomas either is fine at this point but just curious about the coding to make it work for either case. I've just been nesting the function in a number value formula for a quick test.

Answer (score 0):

You want the timestamp to be updated "only when the concatenated range is updated". But the Function you wrote checks if the .Text property is <> "". This is not an "update" check but a check for the existence of a value. You can understand this if you close the file and reopen it, you will see that the date will change because Text <> "" will be true. Another mistake is that you are checking the .Text when you should be checking the .Value. I already answered another 99% similar question and if you want you can see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76157467/15794828